# Dynamically generated moveable vector shapes in Paper.js

Tags: javascript, canvas, vector-graphics, paperjs

I'm trying to render an arrow type shape in Paper.js. I have been able to create the segments that render out the tip of the arrow, but have been unable to create any further points that would finish the outline of the arrow. For my own testing purposes, it's currently only 3 lines, however I need to create a shape that can have fills, etc, so I need to be able to outline the arrow and have the group move dynamically when the mouse is dragged in a direction. I need a fat arrow!

Every point I choose, despite being relative to the position of the current vector, seem to rotate on their own when the arrow is manipulated.

Been hitting my head against this for days with no luck.

Here's what I'm working with -

```
var vectorStart, vector; 

var vectorItem = new Group();

onMouseDrag = function (event) {
    var arrowLength = 50;
    vectorItem.remove();
    engaged = true;
    vectorStart = view.center;
    var end = vectorStart + vector;
    vector = event.point - vectorStart;
    console.log('arrow pointer location: ' + event.point);
    var vectorArrow = vector.normalize(arrowLength);
    vectorItem = new Group([
        new Path([vectorStart, end]),
        new Path([
            end + vectorArrow.rotate(120),
            end,
            end + vectorArrow.rotate(-120),
        ]),
    ]);
    vectorItem.strokeWidth = 1;
    vectorItem.strokeColor = 'black';
    this.onMouseUp = function() {
        vectorItem.remove();
    }
}
```

Here's [a link to a Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#S/hZJNS8NAEIb/ypJLEtoureClwYMoiKAgFPHQ5LDdjklIslM2kxQs/e/ubhO7pai5Td5n3p2vQ6BEA8EyWFVAsgimgcStjXuhWQ+SUK9IaJoOQcJSlaqz+EzQsDumYM+eNHa7KE4sgOoVuxYetciN+tkpSSUqFkEPimJ2SBUzn7URWuP+BVROhSFv58kg/bhzDQ324IytYlCRw9bApDu4wF2lRuhL2HNpXgKdnF8CZZN8cjI25ZsYxlXJd1gqYjM/YwAlqhZr4DXmUegaYA4GzWqUwra6ZKGx94xir5KT471LHCviCnUj6vILIm8k8dU4Loa9Pqn2sz/fBBXR+mJrpuksnpqVUEpn5BSnZEcy8cvhGkkQRIub+ZjlqOm/GbMhZawnG4PsugfeksYKPsqtW/riN+ABa7ePcFMLWYUDRkXZ8uHA3nfeeUU/h/X3BR1TdTSHvtEgKrebNlius+M3) containing my code.

What I'm not understanding is how to add points to the Path that generates the arrow in order to create a shape. Everything seems to rotate on it's own and doesn't behave in the way that I need it to.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 4):

A simple way of drawing an arrow outline is by combining 3 rectangles.
`Paper.js` allow you to do this with [Path.unite()](http://paperjs.org/reference/path/#unite-path) method.

Here is an overview of the drawing algorithm

[image]

Here is a [Sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) demonstrating my solution.

```
//
// CONSTANTS
//

// user defined
var STROKE_WIDTH = 40;
var HEAD_LENGTH  = 300;
var STYLE        = {
    fillColor  : 'orange',
    strokeColor: 'black',
    strokeWidth: 5
};

// computed
var WIDTH    = STROKE_WIDTH * 2;
var DIAGONAL = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(STROKE_WIDTH * 2, 2) * 2);


//
// METHODS
//

/**
 * Draws an arrow between two points.
 * For simplicity sake, arrow is drawn horizontally at origin first
 * then it is moved and rotated according to start / end points.
 * It is composed of 3 rectangles which are united into a single shape.
 * @param {Point} start
 * @param {Point} end
 */
function drawArrow(start, end)
{
    // calculate distance between points
    var distance = start.getDistance(end);
    // make sure it is not lower than diagonal
    if (distance < DIAGONAL)
    {
        distance = DIAGONAL;
    }

    // draw rectangles
    var directionRectangle = new Path.Rectangle(new Point(0, -STROKE_WIDTH), new Point(distance - DIAGONAL, STROKE_WIDTH));
    var topRectangle       = new Path.Rectangle(new Point(0, -STROKE_WIDTH), new Point(HEAD_LENGTH, STROKE_WIDTH));

    // move top rectangle to the right
    topRectangle.translate(directionRectangle.bounds.rightCenter - topRectangle.bounds.rightCenter + [ WIDTH, 0 ]);

    // make bottom rectangle by cloning top one
    var bottomRectangle = topRectangle.clone();

    // offset top and bottom rectangles
    topRectangle.position -= [ 0, STROKE_WIDTH ];
    bottomRectangle.position += [ 0, STROKE_WIDTH ];

    // rotate then to form arrow head
    topRectangle.rotate(45, topRectangle.bounds.bottomRight - [ WIDTH, 0 ]);
    bottomRectangle.rotate(-45, bottomRectangle.bounds.topRight - [ WIDTH, 0 ]);

    // join the 3 rectangles into one path
    var arrow = directionRectangle.unite(topRectangle).unite(bottomRectangle);

    // move and rotate this path to fit start / end positions
    arrow.translate(start - directionRectangle.bounds.leftCenter);
    arrow.rotate((end - start).angle, start);

    // apply custom styling
    arrow.style = STYLE;

    // remove construction items
    directionRectangle.remove();
    topRectangle.remove();
    bottomRectangle.remove();
}

function onMouseDrag(event)
{
    // clear canvas
    project.clear();
    // draw arrow according to mouse position
    drawArrow(event.downPoint, event.point);
}


//
// INIT
//

// display instructions
new PointText({
    point        : view.center,
    justification: 'center',
    content      : 'Draw arrow by dragging and dropping with your mouse.'
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that creates an arrow. The object is initialized with mouse down point and draws an arrow with the tip at the point the mouse is dragged to.

```
function Arrow (mouseDownPoint) {
    this.start = mouseDownPoint;
    this.headLength = 20;
    this.tailLength = 9;
    this.headAngle = 35;
    this.tailAngle = 110
}

Arrow.prototype.draw = function (point) {
    var end = point;
    var arrowVec = this.start.subtract(end);

    // parameterize {headLength: 20, tailLength: 6, headAngle: 35, tailAngle: 110}
    // construct the arrow
    var arrowHead = arrowVec.normalize(this.headLength);
    var arrowTail = arrowHead.normalize(this.tailLength);

    var p3 = end;                  // arrow point

    var p2 = end.add(arrowHead.rotate(-this.headAngle));   // leading arrow edge angle
    var p4 = end.add(arrowHead.rotate(this.headAngle));    // ditto, other side

    var p1 = p2.add(arrowTail.rotate(this.tailAngle));     // trailing arrow edge angle
    var p5 = p4.add(arrowTail.rotate(-this.tailAngle));    // ditto

    // specify all but the last segment, closed does that
    this.path = new paper.Path(this.start, p1, p2, p3, p4, p5);
    this.path.closed = true;

    this.path.strokeWidth = 1
    this.path.strokColor = 'black'
    this.path.fillColor = 'black'

    return this.path
}
```

I like the tapered tail but you can get rid of that by fiddling with the constructor lengths.

Here's a [sketch](http://sketch.paperjs.org/#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) with the mouse handling